# How Do I Format Feed Output Properly with WordPress Plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, validation, rss, feed

The following sample plugin lets you access a custom feed url and outputs customized rss contents. In this case, the url is *http:///?feed=custom_user_feed*. The problem is that it is not formatted properly and Google Chrome does not recognize it as a feed. IE and Firefox do on the other hand.

```
/* Plugin Name: Sample Custom User Feed  */

add_action('init', array(new custom_user_feed, "add_feed"));

class custom_user_feed {

    protected $feed_query = 'custom_user_feed';
    protected $title = 'custom user feed sample';
    protected $link = 'http://www.stackoverflow.com';
    protected $urls = array(
        "http://stackoverflow.com/feeds"
        );
    protected $description = 'this is a sample to demonstrate a custom user feed.';
    protected $language = 'en-us';
    protected $itemlimit = 5;


    function add_feed() {
        add_feed($this->feed_query, array(&$this, "output_rss"));       
    }
    function output_rss() {
        $feed = fetch_feed($this->urls);
        $feed->set_item_limit($this->itemlimit);
        echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>';
    ?>          
        <rss version="2.0">
        <channel>
            <title><?php echo $this->title; ?></title>
            <link><?php echo $this->link; ?></link>
            <description><?php echo $this->description; ?></description>
            <language><?php echo $this->language; ?></language>         

            <?php
            foreach($feed->get_items() as $item) {
            ?>              
                <item>
                    <title><?php echo $item->get_title(); ?></title>
                    <link><?php echo $item->get_permalink(); ?></link>
                    <description>
                        <?php echo $item->get_description(); ?>
                    </description>
                </item>

            <?php
            }
            ?>
        </channel>      
        </rss>
    <?php
    }
}
```

Could anybody find an error in the format? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you should also use `header('Content-Type: text/xml')`?

Comment: Wow, that was it. Please put it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to use `header('Content-Type: text/xml');` too ...

Comment: In addition, html description text needed to be escaped like this, `<description><?php echo esc_html($item->get_description()); ?></description>`. For other character escaping methods in WordPress, http://vip.wordpress.com/2011/10/13/key-differences-between-validation-and-sanitization/